# Matlab dtw Distance Time Warp - Undefined function 'dtw' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, input, arguments, double, dtw

**Hey guys,**

I am getting this error, when using the **matlab dtw function**

> Error: input arguments of type 'double'

I have noticed, by trying to analyze some of my own functions, that the matlab dtw function needs double as input. So I tried an example from the matlab page https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dtw.html, but this one gets the same error. What I am doing wrong ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U22Nh.png)

Comment: Post your code instead of a screenshot please

Comment: I already fix it myself. dwt function is part of matlab signalprocessing toolbox and needs to be installed seperatly